# Find the limit as x approaches 0 of : $f(x) = x|x|,$

Tags: calculus, limits

using the definition (mandatory):

$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} \quad (\text{where }a = 0)$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0}$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x|x| - 0} x$$

$$\lim_{x\to0} |x|$$

(DNE).

Thus the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ for $x|x|$ does not exist.

I'm seeing that the solution is $0$, but how is this possible? Is my solution incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Your steps are correct, except for the last part.  The limit as $x \rightarrow 0$ of $|x|$ is $0$.